# Sticky footer with `position: sticky;`

Tags: html, css, layout, sticky-footer

So I already played a lot with sticky footers, using negative margins technics, flexboxes, grid, and even table technics.

I just discovered the `position: sticky;` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) and thought "Yay! All that mess is finally gone!".

Damn it, it looks like I can't use `position: sticky;` to make a sticky footer, as the behavior I want to achieve is the opposite that's done: I want the footer to be stick at the bottom of the screen when there is not enough content to scroll down, and to be after the content when there is enough of it.

Can that be achieved with `position: sticky;`?

Comment: If you are wanting the content to push the footer down, then I don't see why you would use position sticky for this.  All that would do would make it overlap the bottom of the scrolling div.  You could probably do something to use sticky, but I would envisage it probably using bottom padding on the scrolling div the same size as the footer, which would mean it was more hacky and less fluid than the simple flex solution

Answer (score -2):

In [this article](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) you can read how to use `position: sticky` to achieve something similar only with CSS. I think for your problem it is better to use a little bit of JS to control the scroll of the page and add `position: fixed` to the footer if itś necessary.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't see an example of `position: sticky` in that article. I will certainly not use JS to do that, I can easily do it with 3 lines of CSS using flexboxes. This is only a curiosity question.

Comment: Ok, I have only used this to positioning things relative to the top of his parent.